# How to write data from netcdf file to an excel or text file?

Tags: r, netcdf

I have a netcdf file that has 6 dimensions:

```
f=open.ncdf("C:\\BR_Ban.nc")
```

I read the varible `date`:

```
A = get.var.ncdf(nc=f,varid="date",verbose=TRUE)
```

Then I read the variable `Tair` as I did for `date`.
I wrote the two variables to two text files. May anyone help me to write both of them to one text file or excel? This piece of code will write only one variable:

```
write.table(as.double(A),"C:\\folder\\shwon_Br_Ban_flux net.txt")
```

The problem with this variable `date` is that I got a text file that looks like this:

```
"x"
"1"  2004
"2"   1
"3"  0.5
"4"  2004
"5"    1
"6"    1
```

up to

```
"157675" 2006
"157676" 365
"157677" 23.5
"157678" 2007
"157679" 366
"157680" 0
```

As you can see, all in one column "year,hour and day". Is there a way to write the time step "half hourly" in one column, the year in another column and the same for the day?

Comment: why `as.double(A)`? Considering `A` is a matrix to begin with, `write.table(A,"C:\\...")` should copy it as a matrix: using `as.double`, you force `A` to be copied as a vector instead.

Comment: Otherwise since both `Tair` and `date` have `time_counter` as dimension 2, you should be able to write them together as one text file by "rbinding" them: `write.table(rbind(A,Tair),file="C:\\...")`.

Comment: then you just have to transpose before writing: `write.table(t(rbind(A,Tair)),file="C:\\...")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f <- open.ncdf("C:\\BR_Ban.nc")
A <- get.var.ncdf(nc=f,varid="date")
B <- get.var.ncdf(nc=f,varid="Tair")
write.table(t(rbind(A,B)),file="output.txt")
```

As mentionned in the summary for the netCDF file, `date` has 2 dimensions, dimension 1 (the rows) being `datedim` and dimension 2 (the columns) `time_counter`, while `Tair` has also 2 dimensions with `land` as dimension 1 and `time_counter` as dimension 2. So to output them together you need first to `rbind` them since their shared dimension is the columns (`time_counter`), and then transpose.